Minimize $t_1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty e^{-t_{i-1}}t_i$ subject to $t_1\leq t_2 \leq ...$
I am trying to minimize $t_1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty e^{-t_{i-1}}t_i$ subject to $0<t_1<t_2 <...$ numerically to $10$ decimal places. To do this, I approximate the expression to be (practically)
Minimize $t_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{30}e^{-t_{i-1}}t_i$
Subject to $0<t_1<... <t_{30}$
However, the solution is unstable and deviates in 6th-7th decimal places in the Python optimizer I tried (scipy.optimize.minimize). It's roughly $2.36449....$. Is there a way to do this optimization symbolically, or even approximate the solution to any desired precision?

What type is the decision variable $t$?

@A.Omidi It's a continuous variable, $\geq 0$

It seems your deviation may get back to the standard error tolerance in the solver. E.g. when I try to solve that with some global and local solvers (commercial and open-source) this deviation exists. $(+5.99192977804914e-03, 0.00599200699569733, 0.00599200699569732, 5.99200969287023e-03, 5.9920064272662391e-03)$.

I'm not aware of any exact NLP solvers, but MINLP solvers tend to have parameters for numerics. You can make the epsilon smaller, the constraint tolerance tighter, etc. I know this is possible using SCIP (probably PySCIPOpt is what you would want), but other solvers should also handle it (Gurobi, Baron, Cplex, Knitro). I would be able to help out more with PySCIPOpt, as I'm involved with the project. Just bear in mind that tighter tolerances imply more difficulty.

The nonstrict variant of the problem
minimize $t_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n}e^{-t_{i-1}}t_i$
subject to $0 \leq t_1 \leq ... \leq t_{n}$,
has solution $t_1 = ... = t_{n} = 0$ with objective value zero, which can be shown optimal by nonnegativity of all terms in the objective function.
Hence, the strict variant
minimize $t_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n}e^{-t_{i-1}}t_i$
subject to $0 < t_1 < ... < t_{n}$,
has unattained optimal value zero realized by any feasible sequence approaching $t_1 = ... = t_{n} = 0$, for instance $t_n = \epsilon,\; t_{n-1} = \epsilon^2,\; t_{n-2} = \epsilon^3,\;\ldots$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow0$.
The nonstrict result generalizes to infinite dimension, $n=\infty$, and may hint at the behavior of the strict variant for $n=\infty$ (the feasible sequence I've shown only works in finite dimension).

I'm aware of the trivial solution for finite dimensions, which is why I tried enforcing $t_i > t_{i-1} + \eps$ for small $\eps$ in practice. This gave a significantly different result that the trivial solution, which is what I am looking forward. Essentially, you can push the dimension down from $n$ dimensions to $n-1$ by making a few of the first values close to $0$. Ensuring $t_1>0.1$ (say) and the other variables being spaced fixes this.

If you constrain $t_1 \geq a$ and $t_i \geq t_{i-1} + b$ for small $a$ and $b$, my result can still be used to show that the nearest-zero feasible solution, namely $t_1 = a$, $t_2 = a + b$, $t_3 = a + 2b$, and generally $t_k = a + (k-1)b$, is near-optimal. Perhaps even the exact optimal solution (haven't checked). You should thus try to input this solution as the starting point to NLP solvers.
